# Rails message queue - Alternative to RabbitMQ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, sidekiq

I have 4 Rails apps: **App1**, **App2**, **App3** and **App4**.
**App2**, **App3** and **App4** needs to update the same information (an email address for example, something as simple as that) when it has been updated on **App1**.

For now, and since the data I need to sync are not often changed, I went by using my already-in-place Sidekiq implementation to send a post request to the other Apps within a background job. But that definitly does not sounds as an ideal solution. This change is still in it's own branch and has not been yet merge on production. That's why I'm here for.

I've been tackling RabbitMQ as I read it definitely has this capabilities. However, RMQ sound a bit overkill for my use case, IMHO. So I would like to know how would you guys go for? Is there any other lightweight alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the RMQ route you have to do clustering and federation which is very bloated for this kind of a simple problem. You can implement your own worker queue using Redis which Sidekiq is already using it as a message queue. Use RabbitMQ only for critical real time messaging queue systems.

[RPOPLPUSH - Redis](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by federation?